# Json loop and appending results to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with JavaScript loop, because I use keyup function i cant use `html()` function because it add only last result, and with append it doubles results.
How to solve this problem?

```
for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
{
    $('#result').html(' ' + msg[i].info + '</br> ');                               
}
```

Comment: is #result an input field ?

Comment: is div in for results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current code you show above, you remove the content of `#result` for every array element of `msg`.
You need to append the result if you want every array element shown. If you get double as you say, then you have a problem with the returning result from your script.

The correct approach is:

```
$('#result').html(''); //If you want to empty the container before posting results to it
for(var i=0; i<msg.length; i++) {
    $('#result').append(' ' + msg[i].info + '</br> ');
}
```